# Mysql and php w/ html database issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

I want to get data from my sql database into a table with html.

I have writed 1st part of code ended with `?>`

and started with html table and end with html

My code getting only Empty table without getting data from my Database, here the Code, i dont know how to get data with that

```
 <td> 
   <?php echo $result['nazwiskoimie'] ?>
 </td>
```

Here's the full code :

```html
<?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","listap");

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Blad przy polaczeniu z baza: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM 'lista'");                     
?>

<html> 

  <table border='1'>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <?php echo $result['nazwiskoimie'] ?> </td>
      //in this part have problem to get my data from database 
</html>
```

Here's also a screenshot of a result: [Final After a Save my file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBWZ3.png)

Comment: You seem to be lacking a fundamental understanding of how to to interact with a DB, do please google for a tutorial on "how to retrieve data from mysql database"

Comment: Provide with a clear documentation about the snippet. Your snippet looks rubbish. :(

Comment: i just started to learn php and mysql since like 1 month ago, im not an expert :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM lista");;
?>
<html> 

<table border='1'>

<?php

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
<tr>
   <td><?php echo $row['nazwiskoimie']?></td>
</tr>
 <?php
 }
} ?>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\mysqlnauka\listap.php on line 17

line 17: if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

Comment: change
$result =    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM 'lista'");
to
$result =    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM lista");

Comment: Thanks dude ! it Works +1 :)